# Why are not all NUnit Test Categories showing in Test Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, specflow

I have the latest NUnit installed and i'm using it in conjunction with Specflow in Visual Studio. Its been working fine for the past few months but I noticed there was an update done today which I believe is causing my test explorer window to not show multiple test categories.

Instead it only shows the first. I've checked the code that SpecFlow generates and that all seems fine so it seems to me that its an NUnit Test Adapter issue. Is there a way to resolve this?

If I change the test type to MSTest the multiple categories show.

I'm using VS 2015 with update 2

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm seeing the same behaviour.

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix i did, it was a visual studio issue. Upgrade to the latest visual studio and it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 broke the categories. To get them back installing update 3 fixes this.

Comment: I'm on VS Community 2015 Update 3, and it seems categories are still broken. NUnit test classes have `[TestFixture]` and `[Category("whatever")]` but no trait shows up in test explorer